# How to trigger a server side Suitelet Script from Client Script in 2.0?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet script (server side- working on back end) which needs to be triggered from a client script without getting navigated to that Suitelet page.
I tried using `resolveScript` and it makes the script work but it navigates the page to the suitelet page which is blank.

Can anyone suggest me which API to use which will trigger my Suitelet Script but remain on the same page where I m right now?

My Code:

```
  function goToOpportunityRec() {
var rec = curr.get();

/* if i uncomment this setValue, the script stops working

    curRec.setValue({
      fieldId: 'custrecord_awt_status',
      value: 3,
      ignoreFieldChange: true
    }); */

var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
  scriptId: 'customscript_mx_awtitem_sl',
  deploymentId: 'customdeploy_mx_awtitem_sl',
  returnExternalUrl: false
});
suiteletURL += '&id=' + rec.id;
newWindow = window.open(suiteletURL);
```

}

If I remove the window.open, the Suitelet wouldn't trigger.

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I called my suiteletscript when I click button[Client script] on record.

```
function pageInit(context) {
}
  function onButtonClick() {
document.location.href='/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=726&deploy=1';}
exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
exports.pageInit = pageInit;
return exports;});
```